# How do I add c:\python27 to system's PATH

Tags: python, windows

Just downloaded and installed Python27 (C:\Python27). And when I run `python` in cmd. I get :

`'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program batch file.`.

I looked at other posts. And apparently I need to add python to the environment variable PATH. How does one do this in Windows 7?

Comment: before posting a question, please search on google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, you need to add `c:\python27` to the list of directories assigned to the `PATH` environment variable.

This [link - How to set the path in Windows 7](https://web.archive.org/web/20210213041100/http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx) will tell you how to set your path in Windows 7.

This shows you [how to do this with Java](https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.html) as an example, but you can adjust it to Python

A summary from the web:

Set the system’s PATH variable:

- Right-click Computer and select Properties.
- In the dialog box, select Advanced  System Settings.
- In the next dialog, select Environment Variables.
- In the User Variables section, edit the PATH